# How to solve KeyError in my code?

Tags: python

I have the following code piece:

```
weights = [0.1, 0.2]

ranks = {}
for product,Rank in myDictionary1.items():
    ranks[product] = {}
    for p2,score2 in Rank:
        p2 = int(p2)
        product = int(product)
        if product!=p2:
            ranks[product][p2] = score2*weights[0]
for product,Rank in myDictionary2.items():
    for p2,score2 in Rank:
        p2 = int(p2)
        product = int(product)
        if product!=p2:
            ranks[product][p2] = score2*weights[1]
```

I get the error `KeyError: 655` at this line of my code:

```
ranks[product][p2] = score2*weights[1]
```

However, there is no other detail about the error.

If I correctly understand the error, it means that the key `product` or `p2` do not exist in `ranks`, right?

How can I add the value `score2*weights[1]` to `ranks[product][p2]` if `product` or `p2` do not yet exist in `ranks`?

Comment: `ranks[product] = dict(p2=score2*weights[1])`

Comment: @GarbageCollector: Basically, I want to check if the key exists. If it does not exist, I want to run `ranks[product] = {}` before `ranks[product][p2] = score2*weights[1]`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You alter `product` via `product = int(product)` between

```
ranks[product] = {}
```

and

```
ranks[product][p2] = score2*weights[0]
```

So the new integer `product` is no longer guaranteed to be a key in `ranks`. Move that conversion line all the way up to the beginning of the loop:

```
product = int(product)
ranks[product] = {}
# rest
```

In the second loop you take no measures to check if those products are even present in `ranks`. Generally, you could ease your life using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and a function in order to avoid repeating yourself:

```
from collections import defaultdict

weights = [0.1, 0.2]
ranks = defaultdict(dict)

def process(dct, wght):
    for product, Rank in dct.items():
        product = int(product)  # convert here
        for p2, score2 in Rank:
            p2 = int(p2)
            if product != p2:
                ranks[product][p2] = score2 * wght

process(myDictionary1, weights[0])
process(myDictionary2, weights[1])
```

Comment: I have two for each loops. In each of these loops I might find different `product`. I'm not sure that I understand correctly your proposal. Could you please post my code with your updates?

Comment: Can I use `ranks[product] = ranks.get(product,{})` instead of `if product not in ranks: ranks[product] = {}`?

Comment: @Markus `ranks.setdefault(product, {})`